# Extracting Latitude and Longitude using python

Tags: python, geocoding, latitude-longitude

I'm trying to extract the Latitude  and Longitude from actual address.

I have seen some videos that help me to write the following script, but i have an error showing

```
Lat=Geocode_Result[0]["geometry"]["Location"]["Lat"]
KeyError: 'Location'
```

```
  import pandas as pd
  import googlemaps code
  df=pd.DataFrame({'Address':['9 RUE DU FOSSE, L-7772, luxembourg', '37 RUE DE LA GARE,
  L-7535, luxembourg']})      # Creating a dataframe with 2 addresses (its just an example)              
  Gmaps_key=googlemaps.Client("xxxxxxxxx")

  df['Latitude'] = None
  df['Longitude'] = None

  for i in range(len(df)):
   Geocode_Result=Gmaps_key.geocode(df.loc[i,'Address'])  # sending a request for each of the addresses

  Lat=Geocode_Result[0]["geometry"]["Location"]["Lat"]  # Extracting the Latitude information
  Long=Geocode_Result[0]["geometry"]["Location"]["Long"] # Extracting the Longitude information
  df.loc[i,'Latitude'] = Lat   # Pass the information into the DataFrame
  df.loc[i,'Longitude'] = Long

 print(df)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to first install geopy (pip install geopy) and import Nominatim. I have made few modifications to your code to get the output.

```
import pandas as pd
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim

df=pd.DataFrame({'Address':['9 RUE DU FOSSE, L-7772, luxembourg', '37 RUE DE LA GARE,L-7535, luxembourg']})         
df['Latitude'] = None
df['Longitude'] = None
locator = Nominatim(user_agent="myGeocoder")
for i in range(len(df)):
    location = locator.geocode(df.loc[i,'Address'])
    df.loc[i,'Latitude'] = location.latitude   
    df.loc[i,'Longitude'] = location.longitude
print(df)
```

Output:

```
                                 Address Latitude Longitude
0    9 RUE DU FOSSE, L-7772, luxembourg   49.789   6.06569
1  37 RUE DE LA GARE,L-7535, luxembourg  49.7684   5.52118
```

Comment: dear@Priya, thanks for your contribution. I have one question to the attached code. Does the attache code use the Google API as well,  I was wondering if I can use free service to convert the address (without using Google service)

Comment: The code does not use Google API. It's free only. It is similar to how you install Pandas (pip install pandas) . You just need to install geopy.

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying there's no key `Location` in `Geocode_Result[0]["geometry"]`. Try printing the object?

```
print(Geocode_Result[0]["geometry"])
```

What does the docs say about the response you get?

Also, try using `location` instead of `Location`?

Comment: Can't help you with question 2 as I don't know any geocoding lib. Try googling which geocoding python libraries are available.